# Unstructured disk file conversion

Tags: hp-nonstop, tandem

I am working on TACL/OSS environment where I need to make a copy of unstructured disk file and then work on it. FUP DUP command creates a new copy of file which is unstructured one.
I have code written in Unix for manipulating a file(.txt) tested on my local system. But the same code does not work for unstructured disk file. Is there any way to access(read/write/modify) the unstructured disk file on Tandem system through Unix or Python 2.7, OR able to convert that file into text format using TACL commands?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regular Unix-style tools with the file.
Files in the local Guardian space are addressable through /G/disk/subvol/file

So my Guardian file $as.temp.test is the same as /G/as/temp/test

And in OSS I can do things like:

```
cat /G/as/temp/test
head -c 8 /G/as/temp/test
```

You will need the right tools in OSS of course and this won't work if you have an old operating system and the Guardian disk is virtual (but I think this was fixed about 6 years ago).

Comment: The version which I am using is J06.22, cat command works on key sequenced files. I did not try it on unstructured disk file.

Comment: The cat command usage is giving invalid function argument error

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @Andy Simpson has mentioned about the format of path to be used
You might also have to use edittoc to convert the guardian edit file to unix text file

Comment: I got the reference of edittoc in HP reference manual, not familiar with this command . I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: edittoc creates a object of type 180 which can be accessed only in read mode.

Comment: Have you tried changing permissions on the file(the one produced by edittoc), or you can copy the file to oss and operate on it there

Comment: I did, but did not understand what went wrong. Hence i copied the file on local through ftp, converted it to txt and then moved it to OSS path.